# Computing longevity pay - looking up numbers within a set of ranges

Tags: php

I'm a newbie, and am having trouble figuring out how to approach a problem (or to ask the question - please forgive if I'm unclear).

Longevity pay rate is calculated based on years of service:
   `<10=0`
   `10 but <15 = 0.015`
    `15 but <20 = 0.0225`
    `20 but <25 = 0.325`
    `>=25 = .0450`

I need to calculate the total amount of longevity pay for a range given a starting years of service and an ending years of service.

For example, if I start with 11 years of service and end with `18` years of service, I'd need to add together the salary multiplied by the rate for "`10 but <15`" the number of years in that range (in this case, `15-11=4`) and add that to the salary multiplied by the rate for `"15 but <20"` multiplied by the number of years in that range (in this case, `20-18=2`).

I am not sure how to structure this. I could do an outrageous number of `if/elseif` statements but I know there must be a better way. If someone could point me in the general direction (is there some way to look up numbers within a range and return a value?) I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to algorithms, start by solving it longhand (yourself in steps, not the computer).

Do this as many times as you need to become clear how it's solved.

For example, for the 11 to 18 years (inclusive) scenario, you would get:

```
    year 11; 0.015
    year 12; 0.015
    year 13; 0.015
    year 14; 0.015
    year 15; 0.0225
    year 16; 0.0225
    year 17; 0.0225
    year 18; 0.0225
```

Total longevity pay is (4 * 0.015) + (4 * 0.0225) = 0.15

Be sure to use good attention to detail with your figures (the figure 0.325 you posted in the 20 to 24 year range should probably be 0.0325).

You need to be very confident you know what the right answer will look like for a few test cases, before you start programming it. That way, you can verify the result of your program is correct.

For writing the code, there are probably two ways you could go:

1. Write it in a loop:

   ```
   for ($x = 11; $x <= 18; $x++) {
       (some if/then statements)
   }
   ```
2. Calculate the number of years in each range and multiply by the result. You will need to use the min and max functions at least:

   ```
   $totalpay = 0;
   $totalpay += 0.015 * (you figure out the number of years in 10 to 14 years range);
   $totalpay += 0.0225 * (you figure out the number of years in 15 to 19 years range);
   etc
   ```

This looks like a first year computer programming exercise. Rather than give you a working solution, I prefer to explain how to go about writing it yourself (so that you get the benefit of the exercise).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, it does look like a first-year programming exercise :-) but I am not in school, just trying to figure it out to do something useful on my own.